# Is this understanding of sufficiency correct?

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics

If $X$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, I know that any $g(X)$ where $g(X)$ is one-to-one is also a sufficient stat. However, does that mean that $(X,Y)$ is also a sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

On the one hand, I'm thinking it is because semantically, since $X$ is "sufficient". Doesn't that mean that adding more to it will not destroy its sufficiency?

On the other, I'm thinking it is not because, from the definition of sufficiency, it is possible that evaluating the conditional probability will not yield an expression that is independent of $\theta$ when $Y$ is added to the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you add information from the data in addition to a sufficient statistic you will still have a sufficient statistic. However, it is a minimal sufficient statistic that should be sought because the idea is to use the statistic that is smallest. For example, the sample mean from a normal distribution with known variance is a minimal sufficient statistic for the population mean.

Comment: Ok. The question in the problem that I am dealing with just wants me to determine if the random pair (X,Y) is s sufficient stat for $\theta$. The pdf of XY is difficult to derive but it is easy to show that X is a sufficient stat.

Comment: Are you referring to the joint distribution of the pair X, Y or the distribution of the product of X and Y?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the joint distribution of X,Y